# Cannot change soap URI in envelope using java SoapMessage

Tags: java, uri

I'm trying to create a simple SOAP message to send from a client, but I am (seemingly) unable to change the URI of the "soap" namespace in the envelope.

This is what the soap header SHOULD look like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope/"  soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding/"> ... </soap:Envelope>
```

So I have the following code:

```
    final SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();

    final SOAPPart sp = sm.getSOAPPart();
    final SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();
    final SOAPHeader sh = se.getHeader();
    final SOAPBody sb = se.getBody();

    se.removeNamespaceDeclaration(se.getPrefix());
    se.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope");
    se.setPrefix("soap");
    sb.setPrefix("soap");
    sh.setPrefix("soap");
    se.setEncodingStyle("http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding/");
```

However, when I print the message before sending, the following is my envelope:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding/">
```

Notice the differences in the URIs of xmlns:soap in the "should-be" section and the actual.

If I change the first argument of the `addNamespaceDeclaration` call to "soapy" instead of "soap", this is the following envelope I get:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapy="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding/">
```

I'm guessing it may have something to do with the fact that the call is `addNamespaceDeclaration` rather than something like `changeNamespaceDeclaration`, and it is ignored considering the namespace is already present, but I cannot find something that works (I've already tried `setAttributeNS`).

EDIT: I just realized that `setAttributeNS` is silly because that's changing the namespace, not the URI.
EDIT AGAIN: I'm a little confused, as I continue to search I see sometimes that the naming goes `soap:"Namespace"`, so in that sense I do want to change the namespace... but I thought the namespace was the "soap" part. Any clarifications?

This is my first post so I apologize if I'm asking something that has already been solved, but I've searched around and most of what I've found is related to changing the namespace (like from SOAP-ENV, which is the default namespace, to soap) rather than the URI itself. Thanks in advance.

-M

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general you should not need to manually modify the SOAP namespace. What you probably want to achieve is to create a SOAP 1.2 message (which has a different namespace than SOAP 1.1). Try removing all namespace altering lines from your code and change the first line to

```
final SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();
```

In case you REALLY need to specify which prefix that should be used, this code seems to work:

```
SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage();
sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().setPrefix("soap");
sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().removeNamespaceDeclaration("env");
sm.getSOAPHeader().setPrefix("soap");
sm.getSOAPBody().setPrefix("soap");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply erik, however I tried that about 5 minutes before your post and saw that the default namespace had changed from "SOAP-ENV" (which I had changed to "soap") to "env":

`<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <env:Header/> ... </env:Envelope>`

I really need the envelope to match what I had originally posted - any other suggestions? Maybe I just need to build the message as it seems both of the protocols supported by MessageFactory are not quite right...

Comment: The prefix (e.g. `env` or `soap`) has no semantic meaning, it is only a shortcut to reference the namespace (e.g. `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope`).

Comment: Good to know, however I believe the device that I am communicating with requires that those fields be that way in the request (I think).

Comment: It turns out, the device that I am communicating with requires a message with a fairly specific structure, and although `SOAPMessage` is quick and nice to use, it doesn't seem to be very malleable. I ended up going with the use of `Document` to accomplish my needs - it is not as quick, but it gives more control over style of structure (at least in my experience).

I'm sure that if I was communicating with a regular SOAP service, then this would've been the correct answer, so I'll mark it as so (once I reach 15 rep that is :P).

Comment: With a regular SOAP service, you wouldn't need to bother with which prefix to use :) Good luck to you!

Comment: `What you probably want to achieve is to create a SOAP 1.2 message (which has a different namespace than SOAP 1.1). ` this saved me. It made me dig into binding and finally was able to solve the issue. Thanks a lot.